# how to split a list into separate values in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, pipeline

output of list.py is ['test1','test2','test3']

when I use list.py in jenkins declarative pipeline to create dynamic stages,

```
                output = sh(script: "python3 list.py", returnStdout: true )
                
                for(int i=0; i < output.size(); i++)
                {
                    stage(output[i]) 
                    {
                        echo output[i]
                     }
                      
                 }
```

I get the output as
stage 1: [

stage 2 : t

stage 3 : e

stage 4:  s    ....... and so on it splits element by element

But the actual output should be,
stage 1:  test1

stage 2 : test2

stage 3 : test3

How to get this output ,how to split to get only the values of the list in jenkins declarative pipeline????

Answer (score 0):

`output` is a string variable and not a list. (`output = "['test1','test2','test3']"`)

Solution: convert `output` to a list

```
         output = sh(script: "python3 list.py", returnStdout: true ).replace('[','').replace("'",'').replace(']','').split(',')
         for(int i=0; i < output.size(); i++) {
             stage(output[i]) {
                 echo output[i]
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned output from a `sh` (or `bat`) step will always be a string, which you can then convert as needed to any other groovy object.
Because you output is actually in groovy format you can just use the `evaluate` function to run the output and get it as a groovy list.
Something like:

```groovy
def output = sh script: "python3 list.py", returnStdout: true
def values = evaluate "return ${output}"
values.each {
    stage(it) {
        echo it
    }
}
```

You can also use `def values = Eval.me("['test1','test2','test3']")` but it will require an admin approval to use the `Eval` method.

An alternative will be to parse the string by yourself by removing all `[` `]` and `'` characters from the output string and then splitting it by comma (`,`).
Something like:

```groovy
def output = sh script: "python3 list.py", returnStdout: true
def values = output.replaceAll(/[\[\]']/,'').tokenize(',')
values.each {
    stage(it) {
        echo it
    }
}
```